# How can I quickly separate all the edges of a mesh?

Tags: modeling

I want to separate all the edge from the default plane. I have the default plane and deleted the faces. With the all edge selected Press the P key and select the **by loose Parts**. But that did not work to separate all the edge. I have select single edge Press P key and select **selection**. I have to do this for 3 times for a single plane. Any other way or how can i separate all the edges on to different layers. Any suggestion or help. Thanks.

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHekT.jpg)

Comment: maybe it helps us, if you tell us what do you want to do with 4 seperate edges? That the seperation by loose parts doesn't work is because the edges are connected. This does only work if the vertices/edges are not connected.

Comment: @Chris. What im trying to do is. Creating 4 walls for different layers. I have extruded the verts and try to separate still did not work.

Comment: i still don't understand, sorry. or do you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcbXx.png

Comment: @Chris yes but i want to separate all the 4 faces in different layers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following answer works with already extruded walls, but you can do it the same way if you only have edges. And to show different options I've made a more complex shape than a square.

1. If you simply want to make **all** faces separate objects, select them all with <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > *Split* > *Faces by Edges*. If you only have edges instead of faces, using <kbd>V</kbd> (*Rip Vertices*) will work, too.
3. Now all faces are separated from each other. Press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate* > *By Loose Parts*.
4. Now each face is a single object.

If you on the other hand maybe want parts of the wall with more than one face to stay together as an object, you can of course join those objects after you did the above steps. Or you can do it a little differently:

1. Alternate selections between faces - for example, select three adjacent faces you want to keep together. Then leave the next face(s) - which should be separated from them - unselected. Select the next one(s) that should be separate, too (sounds more complicated now than it is).
2. Hit <kbd>Y</kbd> to *Split Selection*. This way all selected faces get split from unselected faces, while adjacent faces with the same "selection status" are kept together.
3. Now press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate* > *By Loose Parts*.
4. As a result, the alternating selected and unselected faces are single objects.

Of course, depending on the number of faces and selections you are going to make, maybe with the second method you will have the problem that there are two adjacent faces, both selected or unselected, although to be separated they need to be one selected, the other unselected. In these cases you have to split one of those faces in a second turn of the select/split process.

[image: alternate selection]

[image: separated walls]

Comment: step 1 is superfluous -> just select all, V -> separate by loose parts works already (so you save 2 clicks ;))

Comment: @Chris separate by loose parts does not separate

Comment: @Chris Did you try it? Because _Rip_ doesn't work if you have selected all.

Comment: Yes I did. Well - I work on Mac 3.0 - there it works

Comment: I can make a video if you don’t believe 

Comment: @atek You can do the same of course with already extruded walls. You just have to checker select them, so that it's always one selected, one deselected. Then they all become separate parts.

Comment: @Chris plz share the video

Comment: @Chris yes please, on Windows it says "Rip Failed" when I hit V. And you cannot do it with Y either if all are selected.

Comment: here is my video: https://youtu.be/H8YbYdkAxYs

Comment: maybe it's my mac version...so, sorry it does not work for you

Comment: No, it's not working like that on Windows... but that reminded me of a better option to refine my answer.

Comment: @Chris its working on windows this way https://imgur.com/a/anmOhSr. What i did is add the plane. selected all the edge and press v to rip and then separate loose. Thx

Comment: @atek: you are welcome

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks it work this is how its working https://imgur.com/a/anmOhSr

Comment: @atek I've edited the answer because depending on what you want to achieve you can use different methods - although the second would work for the first case, too.

Comment: @Chris Haha, I'm so stupid... of course it works under windows! I don't know what I did differently when it said "Rip Failed" though... But the method of alternating selections is useful for other things, like if you don't want exactly each face to be a separate object. I've edited the answer to show different usages.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from an edges-only plane, (or floor-plan), in Vertex Mode, hit <kbd>V</kbd>.. *Rip*. This will split all selected vertices into coincident pairs.

[image]